# Cannot get from this form PHP

Tags: php

Can you help me? 
Why can't I get content from select?
What add that can I get selected_pos and use it later?

```
$sql = "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'lab_db'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
echo "<form action=\"insert_position.php\" method=\"GET\">";
    echo "<select name=\"selected_pos\">";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<option >",$row['0'],"</option>";
            }
    echo "</select>";


echo "</form>";
if (isset($_GET['upload_table'])) {
    $sel = $_GET['selected_pos'];
    echo $sel;
}


?>
<form action="insert_position.php" method="GET">
    <input name="upload_table" type="submit" value="Загрузить таблицу">
</form>
```

Comment: Your option has no value attribute

Comment: be sure from your lab_db database name that is typed correctly

Comment: echo "<option value='$row['0']' >",$row['0'],"</option>";

Comment: try it and tell me

Comment: @Kisaragi - If it doesn't have a value, the text will simply be used instead.

Comment: Check the generated HTML and see if that looks correct or not.

Comment: I've tried but can't get the content of selected option

Comment: You have two different forms. If you submit the last form, the select won't get sent since it's in a different form. Create _one_ form that you put all the inputs/selects you want to send.

Comment: His submit button is in the second form, while his select is in the first. Yeah, that won't work!

Comment: Okay, thank you! I gonna try.

Comment: Oh, really! It's working! Thank you everyone!

Answer (score 1):

The submit button will, by default, submit the form that it is in. Since the `<select>` element is inside another `<form>` it will not be submitted when the submit button is clicked.

In order to fix your problem, simply add the submit button to the same form where the select element is located.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'lab_db'";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    echo '<form action="insert_position.php" method="GET">';
        echo '<select name="selected_pos">';
           while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
           {
              echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
           }
        echo "</select>";


    if (isset($_GET['upload_table']))
    {
        $sel = $_GET['selected_pos'];
        echo $sel;
    }
?>
    <input name="upload_table" type="submit" value="Загрузить таблицу">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I had no idea you can use commas as well. I will edit.